# Accessing to $this in a inherited function

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance

I can't figure out what is going on here.
I know that every now and then you must explicitly bind "this" to a function to have access to it

```
myclass: {
    test: function(){
        console.log(this.property);
    }.bind(this);
}
```

I have two objects, `father` and `child`, that I extend to have all the properties merged. I use $.extend with "true", to have a deep copy and using a brand new object in order to not modify the original objects.

```
var father = {

    mydata: {
        age: 49
    },

    mymethods: {
        showMyAge: function() {
            console.log(this.mydata.age);
        }
    }
};

var child = {
};

var obj = $.extend(true, {}, father, child);

obj.mymethods.showMyAge();
```

The output is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'age' of undefined
```

Ok, I said. It's the bind(this) thing. Quite simple.
So, I tried to add bind(this)

```
var father = {

     /*...*/

    mymethods: {
        showMyAge: function() {
            console.log(this.mydata.age);
        }.bind(this)
    }
};
```

Again

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'age' of undefined
```

I tried

```
obj.mymethods.showMyAge().bind(obj);
```

Same error.
Then I found out that If I flat the father's method of one level it works!

```
var father = {

    /*...*/

    mymethods: {
        /* moved showMyAge method from here ... */
    }

    /* to here */
    showMyAge: function() {
        console.log(this.mydata.age);
    }
};
```

Output is correct

```
49
```

Why is this happening? Of course, this is not a solution for me, because I have a very complex object containing sub-objects, containing methods.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: becuse if you call `obj.mymethods.showMyAge()`, then `this === obj.mymethods` and `obj.mymethods.mydata.age` doesn't exist.

Comment: *"I know that every now and then you must explicitly bind "this" to a function to have access to it"* although this is sentence is technically true, the statement is feels sooo wrong. Please, there's like a trillion articles out there explaining `this` in JS. Please go and read some of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this way:
`obj.mymethods.showMyAge.call(obj);` or `obj.mymethods.showMyAge.apply(obj)`;

[apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) use arguments as array: `yourFunction.apply(valueForThis, arrayOfArgs);`

[call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) require arguments to be listed: `yourFunction.call(valueForThis, arg1, arg2, ...,argN);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is correct, unfortunately not suitable for me because (beside the example) the showMyAge function is not called from outside, but from inside granpa class! So I don't have final object in that point to use "call" or "apply". Anyway, this was not clear from the example. So your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your object in an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). This creates a private variable (`that`) within a closure. You can then refer to `that` as your father object.

```
var father = (function() {
  var that = {
    mydata: {
        age: 49
    },

    mymethods: {
        showMyAge: function() {
            console.log(that.mydata.age);
        }
    }
  };
  return that;
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is correct, but it does not take care of hierarchy of properties that are merged with $.extend. For an example, just put add mydata: {age: 20} to "child" class. It will print "49" (father's age) because it seems to me that with IIFE solution objects remain separated and properties are not merged to implement the correct hierarchy and the correct override that i need.